# Grails 2.0 artifacts being published to maven central / codehaus repository

Tags: grails, maven, grails-2.0

The recently released Grails 2.0 jars don't appear to be available in the [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.grails%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.0%22) or [codehaus](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/grails-core/) repositories. Are there any plans to publish them there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're at http://repo.grails.org/grails/core and you can browse the repo at http://repo.grails.org/grails and search by group/artifact/version at http://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/gavcsearch.html

Comment: Thanks for that. Did I miss that being mentioned in the documentation somewhere? Also, do they eventually turn up in central?

Answer (score 1):

Grails has an artifactory configured at http://repo.grails.org